# What design pattern for browsing hierarchies in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, hierarchical-data

I'm relatively new to Xamarin Forms and I am unsure which is the best approach for a relatively common requirement.

I have a hierarchy of product categories (over 3 levels) which I would like to drill down on.

I've looked at MasterDetailPage class described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage/) but from what I can see (and as the name suggests) this only supports one level. I'm not sure whether nesting MasterDetailPages could work - it doesn't feel like the right approach to me.

Is there a standard design pattern I should be considering?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from changing the side-bar contents to something else, after the first click by manipulating it.

If your going with this approach your going to want to pay attention to how you handle a back navigation, as you will need to set the side bar contents to the correct level when popping pages from the navigation stack.

Alternatively, have the side-bar showing the first level.  Upon clicking a top-level item, show a detail page with the first sub-level menu items, and when clicking the sub-level item on the detail page, load another detail page with a more refined set of menu/product category items.  In that way the user will always have access to the top-level menu items in the side-bar, to quickly navigate somewhere else.

One last suggestion, would be like the first, having your top-level main menu items shown.  Upon clicking one of these menu items, you expand a list of sub-level menu-items underneath it with some animation / visibility change, so they can still remain on the side-bar, to drill down to a more refined sub-level of menu / product category.  Clicking on one of this further menu item list would then navigate to a detail page.

Comment: Wow Pete, some great suggestions there - I'll certainly consider these and post back anything related to this that I think may be useful to others.